# CHANGE FORMAT TIME IN OBJECTIVE-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I need to change the format of my time and my date  I search in Google how do that and I find how I can change the data format with that code:

```
NSString *hora=@"01:32";
NSDateFormatter *formatHora = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatHora setDateFormat:@"hh:mm"];
NSDate *dateHora = [formatHora dateFromString:hora];
[formatHora setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
NSString* horaFormatoCorrecto = [formatHora stringFromDate:dateHora];
```

But I try the same with the time and the code don't go, I need change the format of the date to 24h, my code:

```
NSString *hora=@"01:32";
NSDateFormatter *formatHora = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatHora setDateFormat:@"hh:mm"];
NSDate *dateHora = [formatHora dateFromString:hora];
[formatHora setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
NSString* horaFormatoCorrecto = [formatHora stringFromDate:dateHora];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Both code are same, please post the code you have tried second time. What are you trying to do, it is not clear from your question !

Comment: In the first code I want change the style of the date and the code run and in the second code I want do the same but in the time 
therefore the code are the same @MidhunMP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below code -

```
    NSString *hora=@"01:32 PM";
    NSDateFormatter *formatHora = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatHora setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
    NSDate *dateHora = [formatHora dateFromString:hora];
    [formatHora setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
    NSString* horaFormatoCorrecto = [formatHora stringFromDate:dateHora];
```